# C# : WPF Mouse Over

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseover

I need to create a WPF application , which contains two windows.. the window1 contains a button. i need to show the second window when the cursor is over the button in first window
[ Like tooltip ] . if the mouse leaves,  the second window should close..

I'm new to WPF. can any one help me with a sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible to do without your second window something like this is usually done in a tooltip, which has exactly that behaviour. (e.g. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/FancyWPFTooltip07132008214937PM/FancyWPFTooltip.aspx)

Comment: Can we do the same in `Winforms`

Comment: In Winforms it is a little harder to make a customized ToolTip that will not just display text. You can pass in an IContainer to handle those scenarios. But I'm not firm in forms anymore :/. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecft989x.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check out [System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx). It is maybe what you are seeking.